# 'not in' not working but 'minus' working fine in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get the entries from one table that are not in another, using `Oracle DB`.

The following query does not return any records:

```
select distinct FOO from TABLE_A where FOO not in (select distinct FOO from TABLE_B)
```

But the following returns records as expected:

```
(select distinct FOO from TABLE_A) minus (select distinct FOO from TABLE_B)
```

**Why does the first query not work?**

Things I've checked:

- I've tried removing the distinct keywords but no luck.
- I've executed the query and subquery individually and they return the expected results.
- I've replaced the subquery with a list of values - works as expected.
- I've aliased the column names - no change.
- The column data types are identical.
- I couldn't locate anything in the way the tables are set up that could create problems.

Comment: Does `table_b` contain any rows where `foo` is `null`?

Comment: Yes, there are some records in TABLE_B where FOO is null.

Comment: `not in` is soooooo last decade. `where not exists` is where it's at nowadays

Comment: add `where foo is not null`. `NOT IN` behaves as `AND` amongst the resultant values set i.e. <> 'A' AND <> 'B' and <> NULL which evaluates to Unknown due to `NULL`. and there is no need of `distinct` inside `not in`

Answer (score 2):

Use `not exists` with a subquery:

```
select distinct s.FOO
from TABLE_A a
where not exists (select 1 from table_b b where b.foo = a.foo);
```

When *any* `b.foo` is `NULL`, then *all* rows are filtered out.  In this case, the `not in` returns either FALSE or NULL.  The condition never returns TRUE.

`not exists` has the expected semantics.

I should add that when using `in` (and `not in` if you still want to use it), then `select distinct` is not needed in the subquery.